# How should I create an SSRS report with a "separate" data output?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am wondering what the "best practice" is for building an SSRS report where the "data output" (CSV/XML) differs greatly from the visual report output. For example, my visual output has a tablix with a computed expression column that creates a formatted address block, but I would like my data output to include street/city/state/postal_code (and so on) in separate columns.

What I have tried so far is to add extra individual fields to the tablix, then use the "Column Visibility" setting and DataElementOutput properties to suppress all of my "data" columns from visibility, and suppressing all of my visible columns from data output.

This works OK in terms of outcome, but when developing in Visual Studio, my tablix is far larger than it really should be because it contains all of the "data" columns that won't actually be visible. So it's more difficult to see what the end result will actually look like. Also, certain properties like column visibility needed to accomplish this must be set on the individual level, which is tedious (column visibility doesn't appear to be listed in the properties pane).

So, I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this outcome in a way that is easier to work with in Visual Studio.

Comment: You could create two separate tablixes and then set the visibility of the entire tablix instead of the columns.

Comment: You should put that as an answer...